# Keep data from a view to another view with BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I'd like to keep information from a view to another view using BackboneJS.

For example, I'm in the page `#home`, and I'm going to the page `#message` (using the function navigate, or directly by changing the URL after the #), but I want to keep the user data from the model of the page `#home` and display them in the page `#message`.

The model is set by the user (with a form) and not from the server/database.

I don't really know what is the best solution to keep those information.

Some code:

view1.js:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'app',
    'text!../../templates/template1.html',
    '../../models/model1',
    ],
    function (Backbone, _, app, myTemplate1, myModel1) {

        'use strict';

        var myView1 = Backbone.View.extend({

            model: new myModel1(),
            template: myTemplate1,
            initialize: function() {
                //
            }
        });
        return myView1;

    }
);
```

view2.js:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'app',
    'text!../../templates/template2.html',
    '../../models/model2',
    ],
    function (Backbone, _, app, myTemplate2, myModel2) {

        'use strict';

        var myView2 = Backbone.View.extend({

            model: new myModel2(),
            template: myTemplate2,
            initialize: function() {
                //How to access data from the model1 here???
            }
        });
        return myView2;

    }
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's what Models are for. Keeping your data. Unless actual navigation is happening (rather than usage of the history API), there is no need to use localStorage or a Cookie.

Comment: My issue is: How to access the model then? By saving the model object in a global variable?

Comment: What do you mean? It's a JavaScript variable you have access to it. I recommend you check out http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/ it's a free book, check out the examples/design there.

Comment: Edited, added some code.

Answer (score 0):

Have your router get the model from view1 (add a `view`.getModel()` method perhaps) and pass it along to view2 as a constructor option.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the appRouter to pass a model to `view1`, but to 'store' the model locally within the approuter.

Then when you go to the `#message` view you can also pass the model to there (or create one if it doesn't exist yet).